# Rails admin Date fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

when I update or create a record that has Date fields it works fine when the locale en but when the locale ar it set nil value do I miss anything

```
ar:
  date:
   formats:
    short: "%B %Y"
    short_month: "%B %Y"
    short_day_month: "%B %d"
    short_day_month_year: "%d %B %Y"
    short_day_month_year_weekday: "%A %d/%m/%Y"
    month_only: "%B"
    short_month_day_year: '%B %-d, %Y'
    long: '%d %B %Y'
```

Comment: I get deep into a lot of solutions all of them solve that by format but in my case formate is not solving the issue finally I figure out that my issue caused because Datepicker passed numbers in ٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩ style and rails can not convert that style to date.
can you help me by fixing this issue to force Datepicker to pass the date in 0123456789 numbers type even when the locale ar
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try defining them under the time key instead of date

```
ar:
  time:
   formats:
    short: "%B %Y"
    short_month: "%B %Y"
    short_day_month: "%B %d"
    short_day_month_year: "%d %B %Y"
    short_day_month_year_weekday: "%A %d/%m/%Y"
    month_only: "%B"
    short_month_day_year: '%B %-d, %Y'
    long: '%d %B %Y'
```

Comment: already exist, it seems like the issue with numbers type the date picker passed number in '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩' style when the locale ar but when the locale en 0123456789 so can I force the date to be in 0123456789 style even when the locale ar